# Is there a "close preference order"?

Tags: discussion

Recently I ran into a question or two that can be closed for either off-topic or being a duplicate.

Is there an order that questions should be closed?

(i.e. close a question as a dupe before closing it as off-topic)

Comment: I generally prefer duplicate, not only does it help the OP, but it provides us with yet another signpost.